# wrong formatting on excel spreadsheet generated on Macbook

Tags: excel

I generated a speadsheet from my website and on my windows machine it generates every column with the right formatting but on a Macbook numbers have "+" signs in between. I do not understand how I can fix this. This is my screenshot generated from a Mac
[image: image showing my results]

Comment: Looks like a formatting thing? Though I can't say I have seen any number format that uses this symbol for thousands separator

Comment: A bit of a band-aid, but you could just find/replace those things out and then reformat the column as a number?